# In my turn, can I just take an "accessible" card into my hand and not play it yet?

Tags: 7-wonders-duel

When selecting cards in Duel, can I select a card and keep it on my hand until I collect money/resource or do I have to sell/play the card immediately?

If I can take the card and not play it yet, can I later sell it or decide what I want to do with it?

Comment: Is there even a concept of "hand" in 7 Wonders Duel?

Comment: @Acccumulation - No, definitely not a thing in Duel.

Answer (score 9):

No, you may not keep the card for later use.

The rules say

> On your turn, you must choose an “accessible” card in the card
> structure and play it. An accessible card is a card which isn’t
> partially covered by other cards.
>
> You can play the card you’ve chosen in one of three different ways: •
>
> 1. Construct the Building • 2. Discard the card to obtain coins • 3. Construct a Wonder

There is nothing in the rules about keeping cards to play later.  You make an immediate choice from the 3 options listed.